loading order multiple deferable views with on idle trigger
If I have multiple deferable views in my template that should be triggered to load on idle, what is the loading order of these views or are all these deferable views loaded simultainiously once the browser is idle?
Example:
@defer (on idle) {
  <first-large-component />
}

@defer (on idle) {
  <second-large-component />
}

If they are loading in order of ocurrence, is there any way to influence their loading order. So in the example above I would like for example to prioritize the loading of the second large component over the first last component.
I read the official documentation but there seems no information on the topic of the loading order of multiple deferable views in a single template.

They are rendered in batches (idle_scheduler.ts:40), you can try on immediate which might have more priority than idle
@defer (on immediate) {
  <child1 />
}

@defer (on idle) {
  <child2 />
}

Stackblitz
But if you have a scenario, where one component depends on the fully rendered other  component, then put Child2 inside of Child1 HTML.

You can combine both idle and immediate triggers in a single @defer instruction separated by a comma to influence their order of execution
@defer (on idle) {
  <first-large-component />
}

@defer (on idle,immediate) {
  <second-large-component />
}


Thanks, that is a nice way to get some more control... Didn't know you could add several triggers.

@Wilt you are welcome, Here is the link for detailed explanation:http://riegler.fr/blog/2023-10-05-defer-part1

I found this now also here in the documentation where they note: Multiple on triggers are always OR conditions. So this would mean the second large component would load on idle or immediate. From reading that I would assume then it won't wait until the browser is idle and it would render immediately in this case. Or am I mistaken?

@Wilt I am not sure about this let me post the same question on twitter group and see

I was wondering did you get any feedback in that twitter group?

@Wilt Sorry I was busy with other work will ask and share that thread here today

No worries, was just curious. Also would like to follow up to be able to close the question, or otherwise I could maybe ask for a feature request for like for example a priority option or similar...

@Wilt
Here is the question I posted on X:https://x.com/che_off/status/1803102037342863761
